# Onclick or eventListener('click') isn't invoking the function as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a login form for my page that will have 2 options "login" and "signup". Similar concept to mini tabs and iframe windows. Basically There is a div for "login" and a div for "signup" side by side. When you click "login" I want a div (currently set for `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden`) to 'expand' (`height: auto; overflow: visible`) when you click "login" (login is a DIV not a submit button, it's like a tab).

I do not understand why it is not invoking the function. During my troubleshooting, I replaced the function with another function in my page that I know is 100% working, but still nothing happens.

I included codes of everything I have tried, I did not use the `onClick` in the HTML tag at the same time as the `addEventListener('click')`. I just included both so the codes are available. Likewise, in the Javascript, I did not do both add class and set height. I tried them independently.

My preferred method is using eventlistener and add class (which should allow the transition effect to work).

HTML:

```
         <div id="login-box">
         <span class="login-head">
           <h5 align="center" class="head">Login</h5><hr />
         </span>
         <ul class="drop-down">
         <li>

         <!-- LOGIN and SIGNUP tabs -->
          <div id="login-title" class="drop-down-head" onClick="loginExpand()">LOGIN</div>
          <div id="signup-title" class="drop-down-head" onClick="signupExpand()">SIGNUP</div>

          <!-- login content to be expanded from 0 height to auto when "login div" above is clicked -->
          <div id="login-content">
              <div class="input column" id="first-name">
                  <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" class="validate white">
                  <div id="first-name-tooltip" class="tooltip">First Name</div>
              </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* default state with 0 height, ideally with a .5s transition 0 height to auto */
#login-content, #signup-content {
  height: 0;
  transition: height .5s;
  -moz-transition: height .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  -o-transition: height .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* class to be added to div */
.expand {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}

/* link-like features to div */
.drop-down-head:hover {
  background: #8fffad;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {

  document.getElementById('login-title').addEventListener('click',loginExpand);
});

function loginExpand() {
  document.getElementById('login-content').style.height=500; //tried this
  document.getElementById('login-content').classList.add('expand'); //also tried this (separately, not together)
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: Just use `!important` in `.expand` in CSS.

Comment: Hi, @Manjuboyz added a response with a snippet that works great. :)

Comment: Glad it worked! as said in the comments you can use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` for transition effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I used `display` than using `overflow`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  document.getElementById('login-title').addEventListener('click', loginExpand);
});

function loginExpand() {
  document.getElementById('login-content').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#login-content,
#signup-content {
  height: 0;
  transition: height .5s;
  -moz-transition: height .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  -o-transition: height .5s;
}


/* class to be added to div */

.expand {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}


/* link-like features to div */

.drop-down-head:hover {
  background: #8fffad;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="login-box">
  <span class="login-head">
           <h5 align="center" class="head">Login</h5><hr />
         </span>
  <ul class="drop-down">
    <li>

      <!-- LOGIN and SIGNUP tabs -->
      <div id="login-title" class="drop-down-head" onClick="loginExpand()">LOGIN</div>
      <div id="signup-title" class="drop-down-head" onClick="signupExpand()">SIGNUP</div>

      <!-- login content to be expanded from 0 height to auto when "login div" above is clicked -->
      <div id="login-content" style=" display:none;">
        <div class="input column" id="first-name">
          <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" class="validate white">
          <div id="first-name-tooltip" class="tooltip">First Name</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That definitely worked. Is there a way to add a transition effect using this method that would have the div "slide down"?

Comment: You can, there is an option `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` which is very helpful for transitioning which is very simple to implement, here is the url https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: Thank you very much. Javascript is a rather new language for me, but I'm learning!

Comment: Here's the actual page if you'd like to see. I didn't do the "signup" part yet, just the login. (the button has been disabled)

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby9LOlo-iulQDhH3aTq8TKXpiyhdeNSHLCT8NVcNuc/dev

Comment: ok, I am not able to open the link may be due I am using ofc machine. If you get the concepts then it is good.

Answer (score 2):

You have issue with the `CSS`. you are assigning the `overflow: visible;` property with `id` selector which has higher precedence than `class`.

`.expand` class will never overwrite this property, hence the `overflow` property will always remain `hidden`. You could use `!important` in the css property to force the browser to use this.

You could handle this by adding the `visible` property using `javascript`.
or use the `class` selector to apply the css.

**Example with Javascript:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('login-title').addEventListener('click', loginExpand);
});

function loginExpand() {
    console.log("clicked");
    let elem = document.getElementById('login-content');
    elem.style.height = 500; //tried this
    elem.style.overflow = 'visible';
    elem.classList.add('expand'); //also tried this (separately, not together)
}
```

```css
/* default state with 0 height, ideally with a .5s transition 0 height to auto */

#login-content,
#signup-content {
    height: 0;
    transition: height .5s;
    -moz-transition: height .5s;
    -webkit-transition: height .5s;
    -o-transition: height .5s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* class to be added to div */

.expand {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
/* link-like features to div */

.drop-down-head:hover {
    background: #8fffad;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="login-box">
    <span class="login-head">
        <h5 align="center" class="head">Login</h5><hr />
        </span>
    <ul class="drop-down">
        <li>
            <!-- LOGIN and SIGNUP tabs -->
            <div id="login-title" class="drop-down-head" onClick="loginExpand()">LOGIN</div>
            <div id="signup-title" class="drop-down-head" onClick="signupExpand()">SIGNUP</div>
            <!-- login content to be expanded from 0 height to auto when "login div" above is clicked -->
            <div id="login-content">
                <div class="input column" id="first-name">
                    <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" class="validate white">
                    <div id="first-name-tooltip" class="tooltip">First Name</div>
                </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Example with Class selector:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('login-title').addEventListener('click', loginExpand);
});

function loginExpand() {
    let elem = document.querySelector('.login-content');
    elem.classList.add('expand'); //also tried this (separately, not together)
}
```

```css
/* default state with 0 height, ideally with a .5s transition 0 height to auto */

.login-content {
    height: 0;
    transition: all 3s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* class to be added to div */

.expand {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: burlywood;
}
/* link-like features to div */

.drop-down-head:hover {
    background: #8fffad;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="login-box">
<span class="login-head">
<h5 align="center" class="head">Login</h5><hr />
</span>
<ul class="drop-down">
    <li>
        <!-- LOGIN and SIGNUP tabs -->
        <div id="login-title" class="drop-down-head" onClick="loginExpand()">LOGIN</div>
        <div id="signup-title" class="drop-down-head" onClick="signupExpand()">SIGNUP</div>
        <!-- login content to be expanded from 0 height to auto when "login div" above is clicked -->
        <div class="login-content">
            <div class="input column" id="first-name">
                <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" class="validate white">
                <div id="first-name-tooltip" class="tooltip">First Name</div>
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I realized that I was using ID instead of class, I did change it to class selectors instead and I added the !important, but I couldn't get it to work :/ I appreciate you explaining this!

Comment: I have added the example with class.

Answer (score 1):

I had added just `!important` to `.expand` in CSS and its working fine.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('login-title').addEventListener('click', loginExpand);
});

function loginExpand() {
  document.getElementById('login-content').classList.add('expand');
}
```

```css
/* default state with 0 height, ideally with a .5s transition 0 height to auto */

#login-content,
#signup-content {
  height: 0;
  transition: height .5s;
  -moz-transition: height .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  -o-transition: height .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* class to be added to div */

.expand {
  height: auto !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}


/* link-like features to div */

.drop-down-head:hover {
  background: #8fffad;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="login-box">
  <span class="login-head">
           <h5 align="center" class="head">Login</h5><hr />
         </span>
  <ul class="drop-down">
    <li>

      <!-- LOGIN and SIGNUP tabs -->
      <div id="login-title" class="drop-down-head" onClick="loginExpand()">LOGIN</div>
      <div id="signup-title" class="drop-down-head" onClick="signupExpand()">SIGNUP</div>

      <!-- login content to be expanded from 0 height to auto when "login div" above is clicked -->
      <div id="login-content">
        <div class="input column" id="first-name">
          <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" class="validate white">
          <div id="first-name-tooltip" class="tooltip">First Name</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your snippet is running great, not sure why it wasn't working for me. I even used class selector (instead of ID) and !important. I'll have to look at mine again. Thank you for your feedback